# returning ajax error from python to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I am doing an AJAX form post in jQuery. However, when I return an error code from my Python server,it's being read as success instead of as error. My code is below. I am a noob in Python. So apologize if I am making obvious mistakes.

Jquery:

```
 $.ajax({

                type:"post",
                url: "/newform",
                data:$('#my-form').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){

                    alert(msg);


                },
                error: function(msg){

                     alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

Python code:

```
def post(self):

    email = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
    id_name = self.get_argument('id1', None)

    try:
        credentials = Credentials(email=email, id_name=id_name)
        credentials.save()

    except Exception, e:
        print '%s' % str(e)
        msg = 'Authorization Failed. Please check if the credentials are correct'
        status = "error"

    else:
        msg = 'Connected'
        status = "success"

    print 'status: %s' % status
    self.write({"status": status, "msg": msg})
```

Comment: "success" only means that the server responded with an HTTP Status code of 200. Your JavaScript has no idea if an error happened on the server side.

Comment: Yes, was making a noob mistake. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is still returning a successful HTTP 200 response, but with "status":"error" in it.

So your javascript could look like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url: "/newform",
            data:$('#my-form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                if (msg.status == "success") {
                //handle success here
                } else {
                //handle error
                }
            },
            error: function(msg){
            //handle server error, such as HTTP 404, 500
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

On a technical level there are no erros. On a functional level there is an error. So the ajax call is done without errors. You have to check in the success handler the status field you are providing for error or success.